# Explain like I'm 5 these 9 methods to compare similar pictures – Hash, MD5, SHA?

Tags: deduplication

Please compare and contrast – like I'm 5, in SIMPLE English – all 9 methods below? English isn't my first language.

[image]

Comment: Short answer, they are all kinds of Hash algorithms. a hash is a one-way translation of a value (a string, a file, really any kind of data) into another normalized form (of the same length and composition). if you hash that value over and over again, you will always get that result, and it should be impossible to find another value that would provide that same result (there are limits on that).  so if a picture compare hashes a picture, and later hashes another picture that produces the same result, they are almost certainly the same picture.

Comment: @FrankThomas Your comment is technically inaccurate, while practically speaking, it is highly improbable statstically for two sets of data to have the same hash value, the possibility is very small but not zero, because hash function outputs a permutation of finite number of elements of a fixed size, there is only a finite number of hashes possible, while there are practically infinite possibilities of input data, the eventuality of two sets of data having the same hash is inevitable, in computing it's called collision, though its possibility is negligible, it can be exploited.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς, I think you are missing some of the nuance to my wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

*Disclaimer: This information was partially based on some quick Google searches, so it may be lacking in some relevant details and/or accuracy.*

---

It looks like the primary differences are in the speed of hash generation and "accuracy" regarding hash matching (how likely or unlikely the hash of one file is to match the hash of another file). Essentially, as you move down the list, the algorithms appear to go from quicker/less "accurate" to slower/more "accurate".

- *aHash* seems to be quick to generate, but hashes for the same items apparently may vary depending on the environment.
- *bHash* didn't seem to have any easily available information about it on Google, other than it appears to be intended to be fast.
- *dHash* and *pHash* are apparently "perceptual" hashes, meaning that (as I understand it) for e.g. `Photo A` and `Photo B`, if `Photo B` is (for example) a resized or slightly altered version of `Photo A`, any generated hashes are more likely to match (obviously, this might apply to other files with minor variations as well, which could be good or bad).
- *MD5* is relatively quick to generate but still has a chance that 2 completely different files could theoretically have the same hash. It is now used mostly to help detect simple file corruption.
- The *SHA* family of hashes are slower to generate (increasingly from *SHA-1* to *SHA-512*) but offer less chance that two files will generate the same hash. This is good for detecting file corruption or (theoretically) malicious tampering.